# Second promise resolve not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Am using the cordova-file-transfer plugin for uploads in my app, am trying to wrap in the plugin in an ionic factory to make my code more modular.

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.factory('$uploader', function($q, $cordovaFileTransfer, $user) {

    this.uploadLogo = function(filepath, vendorId) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var server = encodeURI(logoUploadUrl(vendorId));

        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filepath, this.logoUploadOptions, true)
        .then(function (result) {
            q.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
            q.reject(error);
        }, function (progress) {
            q.resolve(progress);
        });

        return q.promise;
    };

    return this;
});
```

When i use the factory in a controller the first "q.resolve" call is not fired, rather the second one is. I just learned how to use JS promises, and i figure i could be doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the `.then` function takes 3 parameters? I thought it was 2 (success,error). I may be wrong

Comment: `q.notify(progress)` don't resolve it at state when it's going to be called multiple times

Comment: @AbdulAhmad it is correct, the 3rd is progress in that case

Comment: @AbdulAhmad yeah .then() takes 3 arguments

Comment: @maurycy do i call q.notify(progress) in the progress method?

Comment: FWIW: you can only resolve a promise _once_. After that, its "fate" is sealed and you cannot resolve (or reject) it again.

Comment: Yes, call it in progress method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @maurycy for the help. I sorted it out

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.factory('$uploader', function($q, $cordovaFileTransfer, $user) {

    this.uploadLogo = function(filepath, vendorId) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var server = encodeURI(logoUploadUrl(vendorId));

        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filepath, this.logoUploadOptions, true)
        .then(function (result) {
            q.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
            q.reject(error);
        }, function (progress) {
            q.notify(progress);
        });

        return q.promise;
    };

    return this;
});
```